# MySQL - Field <myfield> doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, insert

I am aware that the certain field doesn't have a default value.

I've been using MySQL 5.5.28 and it does work whenever I insert without specifying a value on that field. The field is TINYINT and by default, without specifying any value AND without declaring a default value during creation of the table, a value of 0 will be inserted in that field during INSERT statement.

However, after updating to MySQL 5.5.30, the query doesn't work anymore and is returning **Field  doesn't have a default value**.

I've been looking through the changelogs and didn't find any clue that something has changed with regards to the default values of Integer.

MySQL 5.5.29 : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-29.html#mysqld-5-5-29-feature

MySQL 5.5.30 : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-30.html

Test queries:
**MyTable** has the Fields **MyField1** and **MyField2**

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyField2)VALUES('MICHAEL');
```

Result on MySQL 5.5.28:

**MyField1** | **MyField2** 
0 | MICHAEL

With warning: 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1364 Field 'MyField1' doesn't have a default value

Result on MySQL 5.5.30:

**No changes on data and throws an error**
Error Code: 1364. Field 'MyField1' doesn't have a default value

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyField1, MyField2)VALUES(0, 'MICHAEL');
```

The above query will work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st server strict sql mode was not enabled, while in the 2nd one it was. Read more about strict mode [in the mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

Specifically:

> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings (see Section 13.7.5.40, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”). In strict mode, you can produce this behavior by using INSERT IGNORE or UPDATE IGNORE.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. Found the configuration. After updating the server, the sql_mode has been set to TRADITIONAL which doesn't allow the insertion without specifying the value if it doesn't have default value. I think I may have to check the tables again to apply the necessary changes in the current sql_mode. I might need to stick with the current configuration which I think is much more secure that the default sql_mode.

Comment: Yes, it is more secure.